# How can I attach to global vue error handling

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue2 application I want to find a place where I can catch global Vue errors and send them to a logging/monitoring instance, like Sentry.

When I override the global error handler of Vue, I dont get console logs anymore. Is there a possibility to attach to the global error handler instead of overriding it?

```
const plugin: PluginObject<never> = {
    install(Vue: typeof _Vue): void {
        Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
            // my Sentry stuff        
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to store a reference to the original error handler and then call it from within your custom error handler. This will allow you to both send errors to your logging/monitoring instance and preserve the default error.

```
const plugin: PluginObject<never> = {
install(Vue: typeof _Vue): void {
    // Store the original error handler
    const originalErrorHandler = Vue.config.errorHandler;

    Vue.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
        // Your Sentry or other logging/monitoring code
        // ...

        // Call the original error handler, if it exists
        if (originalErrorHandler) {
            originalErrorHandler.call(this, err, vm, info);
        } else {
            // If there wasn't an original error handler, you can log the error to the console
            console.error(err);
        }
    };
}
```

};